# Quickest way to move bracket at beginning of line to end of above line

Tags: rearrangement

What's the quickest (as far as anyone knows) way to change this:

```
int main()
{
```

into this:

```
int main() {
```

provided the cursor is on the `{`?

Comment: `kJ`?  (and some more text is here because comments need it :) )

Comment: @grochmal That looks like an answer, to me!

Answer (score 1):

It actually took me a little while to figure this out on my own, too: `dh`

Now, I use a macro for "merging" lines like this: `let @m=' 0i ^[0wd0dhi ^['`  This will take the current line, with the cursor positioned anywhere on that line and merge it with the previous line, while inserting a space, and leave you back in NORMAL mode.  Note: the `^[` are escapes gotten by typing `ctrl-r<Esc>` which is control-r then the esc key.  To be sure you've done it correctly, those two characters will behave as one if you try and move the cursor over them.

Put the above line in your ~/.vimrc or ~/.vimrc.local and then either restart vim or do `:source ~/.vimrc`

Comment: `dh` will result in `int main(){`, not `int main() {`, and it only works if you've added `h` to your `whichwrap` setting.

Comment: Previous comment reads more confrontational than I meant it to! Just thought they were caveats to your otherwise nifty technique that might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the `whichwrap` setting.  Learning something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that I think that opening braces on a separate line is the better style, you can do

```
:g/^\s*{\s*$/-1j
```

to append all occurences in the whole file of opening braces in a separate line to the previous line.

If this is your coding style (for some no good reason), you can add this to your `.vimrc` to be executed automatically when opening source code files.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following command in normal mode if cursor is at bracket.

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>